# Do sea days count towards the 90/180 limit in Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

We're flying to Europe and then taking a Transatlantic cruise from Rome back to the US.  I'm trying to find out how many of the 14 cruise days count towards the 90/180 limit in the Schengen area.  Days in port only, all days until we reach international waters, or the total cruise days.  I don't want to cut our days in Europe short if I don't need to, but also don't want to exceed the limit.  The cruise line doesn't seem to know either...  Thanks for any answers or help or advice about where else to check!

Comment: Is your cruise going to call at any Schengen ports again after Rome?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135776/discussion-on-question-by-k-mason-do-sea-days-count-towards-the-90-180-limit-in).

Answer (score 15):

It really boils down to where you will undergo exit border checks. As of April 2022, the length of your stay is still determined based on the stamps in your passport. There is no central database of entries and exits and no way for other Schengen countries to know when you last left than looking at the passport stamps. You will therefore be able to determine how long your stay was based on those stamps (at least in theory).

The Schengen Borders code has special rules regarding checks for cruise ships but I think the last exit check should happen at the last port in the Schengen area. If the ship and its passengers are subject to a full exit border check, you will get a stamp dated from the day you leave the port.

Days at sea between ports in the Schengen area, even in international waters, can count as part of your stay. Days at sea en route to a port in a third country like the US should not count. It doesn't really matter when you reach international waters and cruise days after getting an exit stamp definitely do not count. If you underwent an exit check when boarding the ship, days in a Schengen port where you don't go ashore wouldn't count either. Even short excursions can sometimes be exempted from entry and exit checks.

Comment: And in case you do not receive an exit stamp before boarding, save documentation so that you can prove when you exited Schengen

Comment: We could argue that we left Schengen when the ship left Cartagena for Gibraltar, and re-entered in Gijón two days later.  But our passports only show leaving Gijón.  No evidence of stopping in Gibraltar or time at sea except in our photos.

Comment: @WGroleau Not 100% sure what you are talking about but Gibraltar is a special case as Spain doesn't fully accept that it's not part of its territory.

Comment: Just to note: Azores and Canarias are in Schengen area. Some transatlantic cruises will stop just to make more manageable the cruise (less sea days). But from OP question: Schengen is not Europe, so you can possibly pass few days in UK or other European but not Schengen zone. There is no lack of interesting places outside Schengen.